# Why is res.json returning empty?

Tags: arrays, rest, promise

When I make a "GET" request from the client to the server the server should make a `axios.get()` call to a stock API to retrieve data for an array of tickers. When I console.log the results it seems to be working fine but the array doesn't seem to save, like it gets wiped out and comes back to the client as empty. I think I might be messing this up with `async/await`.

```
async function currentPrice(ticker) {
    const apiURL = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=${ticker}&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
    let price;

    await axios.get(apiURL).then(data => {
        try { 
            price = data.data["Global Quote"]["05. price"];
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
    return price;
};

app.get("/refresh", redirectLogin, (req, res) => {
    const {
        user
    } = res.locals;
    var array = [];
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM holdings WHERE user_name = '${user.user_name}' AND quantity > 0`, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        results.forEach(holding => {
            currentPrice(holding.ticker).then(data => {
                var updatedTicker = {
                    ticker: holding.ticker,
                    description: holding.description,
                    price_acquired: holding.price_acquired,
                    market_price: data,
                    delta: parseFloat(this.market_price) - parseFloat(this.price_acquired),
                    quantity: holding.quantity,
                    trade_date: holding.date_acquired
                }
                array.push(updatedTicker);
                // console.log(array);
                console.log(updatedTicker.market_price)
            })
        })
        res.json(array)
    })
})
```

Comment: You are calling `res.json()` BEFORE any of your `currentPrice().then()` have finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `res.json(array)` before any of your `currentPrice().then(...)` calls have finished, thus the array is still empty.

There are a number of different ways to solve this.  Probably the simplest is to change for `.forEach()` loop to a plain `for` loop and then use `async/await` to serialize each of your calls to `currentPrice()`:

```
function currentPrice(ticker) {
    const apiURL = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=${ticker}&apikey=${API_KEY}`;

    return axios.get(apiURL).then(data => {
        try {
            return data.data["Global Quote"]["05. price"];
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        }
    });
}


app.get("/refresh", redirectLogin,  (req, res) => {

    const { user } = res.locals;
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM holdings WHERE user_name = '${user.user_name}' AND quantity > 0`,  async (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }

        try {
            const array = [];
            for (let holding of results) {
                let data = await currentPrice(holding.ticker);
                let updatedTicker = {
                    ticker: holding.ticker,
                    description: holding.description,
                    price_acquired: holding.price_acquired,
                    market_price: data,
                    delta: parseFloat(this.market_price) - parseFloat(this.price_acquired),
                    quantity: holding.quantity,
                    trade_date: holding.date_acquired

                }
                array.push(updatedTicker);
            }
            res.json(array);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Various changes:

1. Simplified the `currentPrice()` function to just return the axios promise directly
2. Appropriately reject in `currentPrice()` if there's an error so the caller sees the error.
3. Add proper error handling (sending an error response), if the db query fails.
4. Switch `.forEach()` loop to a `for` loop so we can use `await` to serialize the calls to `currentPrice()` so we can more easily know when they are all done.
5. Add error handling and sending of an error response if `currentPrice()` has an error.
6. Call `res.json(array)` only after all the now-serialized calls to `await currentPrice()` have completed.

---

FYI, a fully complete transformation here would switch to mysql2 so you can use the promise interface for `connection.query()` rather than the plain callback interface that you are using now.  That would allow you to consolidate error handling to one place more easily.

Comment: WOW THIS IS AMAZING! Thank you so much for your wisdom the edits work fine!